# Parametrizing Unitary matrices using Hermitian matrices. Covers the whole space?

Tags: parametrization, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

An $n\times n$ unitary matrix can always be written in the form,
$$ U=e^{i\,H}\,,$$
where $H$ is a Hermitian matrix. If we use the generalized Gell-Mann matrices as the basis for Hermitian matrices, does this parametrization cover the whole space of Unitary matrices for a given dimension?

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4156415/can-any-unitary-and-pd-matrices-be-represented-by-exponential-matrix?rq=1

Comment: Thank you, actually the second part of the question was helpful for me in another context, but it really doesn't confirm if the parametrization effectively covers the whole space of Unitary matrices.

Comment: AFAIK, and have talked to people, it should cover the whole space!